# How to read file from specific line and write the output?

Tags: python, io

I want to read from output.txt lines 121-136 and save them in same format to zxyr.txt.File looks like this:

```
>ZYXR //74
-6.440208621086e+03 -4.758666382870e+03 -3.995858566350e+03 -4.934315690511e+03 -5.049765912718e+03 
-4.323241464318e+03 -4.246930447741e+03 -3.836596391287e+03 -3.357569224670e+03 -2.955821531683e+03 
-2.579438902492e+03 -2.291910045847e+03 -1.831407086906e+03 -1.630707014227e+03 -1.376537942484e+03
```

My code

```
from __future__ import with_statement

inFile = open('output.txt','r')
outFile = open('zxyr.txt', 'w')

lines=[121, 136]
i=0

for line in inFile:
    if i in lines:
        counter = str(int(inFile.read().strip())
        outFile.seek(0)
        outFile.write(counter)
    i+=1
```

But

```
  File "ex1.py", line 12
    outFile.seek(0)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to read all previous lines anyway. What about to do:

```
startline = 121
endline = 136
with open('output.txt','r') as inFile:
    lines = inFile.readlines()[startline:endline+1]

with open(zxyr.txt, 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a single range of lines quite cleanly using [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) as follows:

```
from itertools import islice

with open("output.txt", "r") as f_input, open("zxyr.txt", "w") as f_output:
    f_output.writelines(islice(f_input, 121+1, 136+1))
```

To work on a couple of ranges, you could take the following approach:

```
with open("output.txt", "r") as f_input, open("zxyr.txt", "w") as f_output:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f_input, start=1):
        if (121 <= line_number <= 136) or (184 <= line_number <= 206):
            f_output.write(line)
```

Both of these solutions avoid reading the whole file into memory, which is important if the file is large.

Comment: Could I use this for multiple line intervals (121,136) ant latter(184,206)?

Comment: No, unfortunately this approach works for a single range, a slightly different approach though would work, I will update.